# Как вставить переменную в SQL-запрос

Tags: c#

```
SqlCommand SelectDannieComand = 
    new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM tableName WHERE Id > 15", sqlConnection);
```

Как вставить в этот запрос вместо tableName и name переменную?

Comment: Скажите, а вы основы языка C# знаете? Мне кажется, что рань вам еще лезть в такие дебри - как база данных... Ну а вообще, самое элементарное - `"Часть текста " + переменная + "часть текста"` или если используете новые версии C#, то `$"Часть текста {переменная} часть текста"`.

Comment: Думаю, так же следует заметить, что вы не должны "слепо" передавать эти переменные в запрос, полученные от пользователя. Это уязвимость системы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, для названия таблицы не получится использовать `Parameters.AddWithValue`, так что, что-то такое:

```
var tableName = "MyTable";
var columnName = "Name";   
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE Id > 15", columnName, tableName));
```

Comment: вы правы, параметризовать такое явно не получится, альтернатива разве что хранимка с параметрами и динамический SQL внутри, но это по сути то же самое с теми же недостатками, так что предварительная валидация значений на вызывающей стороне необходима.

Comment: @rdorn ну тут таблица и колонка, я так понял, что эти вещи не от пользователя приходят. Если от юзеров, то да, надо экранировать.

Comment: программисты иногда хуже пользователей, так что экранировать лучше от всех =)